# How can I display a variable in a view when the rest are in a loop?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm sorry, I'm not sure how to phrase this question. At the moment I have 3 variables which I want to display to my view. However one of the three is a total amount of money made from claims and I want this variable to be displayed once. Is there any way of doing this?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult About()
    {
        IQueryable<ClaimsDateGroup> data = from claim in db.Claims
                                           group claim by claim.CreatedDate into dateGroup
                                           select new ClaimsDateGroup()
                                           {
                                               CreatedDate = dateGroup.Key,
                                               ClaimCount = dateGroup.Count(),
                                               Total = db.Claims.Sum(c => c.Total)
                                           };
        return View(data.ToList());
    }
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreatedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClaimCount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: What is `Total` meant to be?  I'd expect it to be the total for the claims in that group, but you seem to be calculating the total of all claims multiple times.  It's meant to be the total of all claims, I don't think the property belongs there.

Comment: It is meant to be the total of all claims. This is just a small statistics section of the program and I would like to display three statistics. The date which the claim was created, the amount of claims created on that day and the total of all money made through the claims.

Comment: Please note that the [tag:model-view-controller] tag is meant for questions about the *pattern*, whereas your question is about the ASP.NET implementation, which should use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag. I've added it here for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model, take it outside of the foreach loop and change it to

```
@Model.Sum(o => o.Total)
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way of just holding the total in the method?

Answer (score 0):

2 things

1. Use a separate query to get the total so you'll have a separate single value
2. The total will need to be displayed outside the loop that is building your view table if you only want it displayed once

Comment: How would I be able to pass it to the view though as a view can only have one object passed through. In this case its the object data as a list. If I remove the total from the data list then I wouldnt be able to pass it through

Comment: You'd need a wrapper object that exposed the total and the list as properties. You could then pass the wrapper to the view.

Comment: I just created another query and then put it in a ViewBag. Inefficient, but it works